# %^% operator in R

Tags: r, operators

in order to perform markov chain forecast, i've been encountered to %^% operator. Previously we know that %*% operator would return multiplication for each element within the matrix, but when doing with %^% what should it return.

the following condition as below:

```
ra <- matrix(c(.66, .23, .11, .46, .31, .23, .20, .31, .49), 
             nrow = 3, byrow = T) %>%
  as.data.frame()
ColumnNames  <- c("No Rain", "Light Rain", "Heavy Rain")
RowNames <- c("No Rain", "Light Rain", "Heavy Rain")
colnames(ra) <- ColumnNames
rownames(ra) <- RowNames
      
        No Rain Light Rain Heavy Rain
    No Rain       0.66       0.23       0.11
    Light Rain    0.46       0.31       0.23
    Heavy Rain    0.20       0.31       0.49
```

to perform predict the second day, perhaps we first should,

```
ra2 <- ra %^% 2
```

Comment: From which package, you have the operator `%^%`

Comment: try `install.packages("expm"); library(expm)`

Comment: thanks ben, thats works well contain within expm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably referring to an overloaded operator.

For instance, consider I can have an overloaded operator '%^%' defined as:

```
'%^%' <- function(x,y) x+y

 a <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2,2)

 b <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2,2)
```

Then applying the operator on the matrices a and b will add them according to my operator definition.

```
a %^% b 
    [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    6
[2,]    4    8
```

Also to know what the R operator  means in your context, %^%
You can see the custom operator definition this way:

```
`%^%`
function(x,y) x+y
```

More over, the custom operator can be used like a function call with function name being `%^%` in this case , which is same as operand1 %^% operand2

```
   `%^%`(a,b)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    6
[2,]    4    8
```

So in your case, its a custom operator whose definition is required, before you can use it(implementation can come from a libray as well).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're inferring this from the `%*%` operator. https://www.statmethods.net/advstats/matrix.html maybe this might help with your question.
However, %^% doesn't exist by default, but there's a package for that. Please see this question here as well https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4320/compute-the-power-of-a-matrix-in-r/187477.

Answer (score 0):

You sould write a function to calculate the power of a matrix in R:

```
multi<-function(A,n){
  temp_mat<-A
  for (i in 2:n){
    temp_mat<-temp_mat%*%A

  }
  return(temp_mat)
}
```